# Ubuntu 14.04 Geforce 210 AVCHD hardware acceleration

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, video

I've been trying to achieve hardware acceleration using nvidia driver 340.96 for geforce 210 card on ubuntu 14.04.4, for an avchd 1080p 60fps file.

Both kodi (16.0) and VLC produce stuttering, choppy usuable video.
While playing cpu cores (core 2 duo E6750)  run at 100% & 40%.
Same goes with nouveau driver.

windows 7 plays it flawlessly,so it's probably not a hardware issue.

**vdpauinfo:**

```
   display: :0   screen: 0
API version: 1
Information string: NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  340.96  Sun Nov  8 22:09:55 PST 2015

Video surface:

name   width height types
-------------------------------------------
420     4096  4096  NV12 YV12 
422     4096  4096  UYVY YUYV 

Decoder capabilities:

name               level macbs width height
-------------------------------------------
MPEG1                 0  8192  2048  2048
MPEG2_SIMPLE          3  8192  2048  2048
MPEG2_MAIN            3  8192  2048  2048
H264_MAIN            41  8192  2048  2048
H264_HIGH            41  8192  2048  2048
VC1_SIMPLE            1  8190  2048  2048
VC1_MAIN              2  8190  2048  2048
VC1_ADVANCED          4  8190  2048  2048
MPEG4_PART2_SP        3  8192  2048  2048
MPEG4_PART2_ASP       5  8192  2048  2048
DIVX4_QMOBILE         0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX4_MOBILE          0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX4_HOME_THEATER    0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX4_HD_1080P        0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX5_QMOBILE         0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX5_MOBILE          0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX5_HOME_THEATER    0  8192  2048  2048
DIVX5_HD_1080P        0  8192  2048  2048

Output surface:

name              width height nat types
----------------------------------------------------
B8G8R8A8          8192  8192    y  Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 
R10G10B10A2       8192  8192    y  Y8U8V8A8 V8U8Y8A8 

Bitmap surface:

name              width height
------------------------------
B8G8R8A8          8192  8192
R8G8B8A8          8192  8192
R10G10B10A2       8192  8192
B10G10R10A2       8192  8192
A8                8192  8192

Video mixer:

feature name                    sup
------------------------------------
DEINTERLACE_TEMPORAL             y
DEINTERLACE_TEMPORAL_SPATIAL     y
INVERSE_TELECINE                 y
NOISE_REDUCTION                  y
SHARPNESS                        y
LUMA_KEY                         y
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L1        y
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L2        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L3        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L4        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L5        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L6        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L7        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L8        -
HIGH QUALITY SCALING - L9        -

parameter name                  sup      min      max
-----------------------------------------------------
VIDEO_SURFACE_WIDTH              y         1     4096
VIDEO_SURFACE_HEIGHT             y         1     4096
CHROMA_TYPE                      y  
LAYERS                           y         0        4

attribute name                  sup      min      max
-----------------------------------------------------
BACKGROUND_COLOR                 y  
CSC_MATRIX                       y  
NOISE_REDUCTION_LEVEL            y      0.00     1.00
SHARPNESS_LEVEL                  y     -1.00     1.00
LUMA_KEY_MIN_LUMA                y  
LUMA_KEY_MAX_LUMA                y
```

**mediainfo:**

```
General
ID                                       : 1 (0x1)
Complete name                            : 1.MTS
Format                                   : BDAV
Format/Info                              : Blu-ray Video
File size                                : 3.99 GiB
Duration                                 : 22mn 6s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 25.9 Mbps
Maximum Overall bit rate                 : 28.0 Mbps

Video
ID                                       : 4113 (0x1011)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.2
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=3, N=30
Codec ID                                 : 27
Duration                                 : 22mn 6s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 24.4 Mbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 26.0 Mbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 59.940 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.197
Stream size                              : 3.77 GiB (95%)

Audio
ID                                       : 4352 (0x1100)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : 129
Duration                                 : 22mn 6s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 384 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -34ms
Stream size                              : 60.7 MiB (1%)

Text
ID                                       : 4608 (0x1200)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : PGS
Codec ID                                 : 144
Duration                                 : 22mn 6s
Delay relative to video                  : -34ms
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The new Intel E3, E5 & E7 CPU chips have AVCHD compression/decompression built in. Older CPUs may or may not. It is possible that Windows knows how to access such features while Linux may not yet have this capability in the default kernel.